# JTable drop row makes a duplicate row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem with the below code. Basically I have a JTable. When I move a row it gets to the below method and after:

```
    e.dropComplete(importer.importData(c, t));
```

I get an error which says `Exceptionjava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index`

```
    public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("DropHandler.drop(x)");
        int dropAction = e.getDropAction();

        JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getDropTargetContext().getComponent();
        HookAndEyeTransferHandler importer =
                (HookAndEyeTransferHandler) c.getTransferHandler();

        if (canImport && importer != null && actionSupported(dropAction)) {
            e.acceptDrop(dropAction);

            try {
                Transferable t = e.getTransferable();
                importer.setDropPoint(e.getLocation());
                importer.setDropComponent(c);
                e.dropComplete(importer.importData(c, t));
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                e.dropComplete(false);
            }
        } else {
            e.rejectDrop();
        }
    }
```

The rows move but makes a duplicate. How to code it to *not* duplicate the dropped data?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: "How to code it to *not* duplicate the dropped data?"  I added that question.  Please review and [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18483963/edit) as needed.

Comment: Well, it looks like somewhere (in dropComplete or importData probably) you are not using your data structures correctly, my guess is that if you try to do a SSCCE you will find a simple bug, either accessing data or determining _what_ are you dropping _where_.